# Object Type in List

Tags: java

Good Morning!
I have a method "gerarJasper" that prints a report using JasperReports. This method gets a list as a parameter, so I can use this method throughout my application. However, when this list does not contain any data, JasperReports prints a blank PDF. What I want to do: When the data parameter is empty, I would like to add an object in this list. I have how to find out Object type of a List at runtime
The code below

```
public void imprimir(List<TrUltimaLocalizacaoGps> l){
    try {           
        super.gerarJasper("RelLstTrUltimaLocalizacaoGps", "PDF", l, new HashMap());
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void gerarJasper(String jasperName, String type, List data, Map params) throws IllegalArgumentException, RuntimeException, Exception {

    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < VALID_TYPES.length; i++) {
        if (VALID_TYPES[i].equals(type)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tipo solicitado '" + type + "' inválido");
    }

    ExternalContext econtext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();        
    InputStream stream = econtext.getResourceAsStream(PREFIX + name + SUFFIX);
    if (stream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("O relatório '" + name + "' não existe");
    }

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ServletContext context = (ServletContext)fc.getExternalContext().getContext();
    String path = context.getRealPath(File.separator) + "resources/jasper" + File.separator;
    params.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", path);

    // here I would like to know what the Object Type of the data parameter        
    JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(data.toArray());
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    try {
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(stream, params, ds);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FacesException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    JRExporter exporter = null;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) econtext.getResponse();
    FacesContext fcontext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {
        response.setContentType(type);
        if ("application/pdf".equals(type)) {
            exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());
        } else if ("text/html".equals(type)) {
            exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_WRITER, response.getWriter());                
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fcontext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_MAP, new HashMap());                
            exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, request.getContextPath() + "/image?image=");
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FacesException(e);
    }

    try {
        exporter.exportReport();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FacesException(e);
    }
    fcontext.responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: "*I have how to find out Object type of a List at runtime*" - [Due to type erasure, this is not possible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Also, [do not use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, java's type erasure makes it impossible to find out what type of list "data" is. So you have to think of an alternative for your issue.

**One option is,** since the list is empty, does it really matter what type it was? If not, you can simply create a new List with one item when the input is empty:

```
JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(data.isEmpty() ? Arrays.asList(new SomeObject()), data.toArray());
```

**Another option is,** if the list type makes a difference, you could pass its class as a parameter:

```
public void gerarJasper(String jasperName, String type, List data, Map params, Class<?> listClass) throws IllegalArgumentException, RuntimeException, Exception {
```

And then create a new object when "data" is empty:

```
JRDataSource ds;
if (data.isEmpty()) {
    Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
    Object object = ctor.newInstance();
    ds = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(object);
} else {
    ds = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(data.toArray());
}
```

**Lastly,** instead of adding something to the list when you are generating the report, why not make sure that there is always something in the list when you create it. You likely know what type of list it is when you create it. Depending on how the application is set up, this might make sense.